# Rotary Sensor Potentiometer SP280X series

Tags: potentiometer, rotary

I have a novatechnik rotary sensor potentiometer SP2801 100 002 001.Th datasheet shows that it has a maximum electrical angle of 100 degree.But I saw that we can move the pot in any direction any number of times.Then what does this maximum angle mean and how to locate it if it is there(the datasheet mentions the 0 degree and 100 degree angle).

Answer (score 2):

The electrical angle is independent of the pot's physical ability to turn. In other words, there are no physical stops.

Within the 100 degree operational range, it behaves like a regular pot - with the wiper traversing from the resistor terminal at one end of the "electrical" range to the terminal at the other end (100 degrees apart). When you go outside this range, the wiper would be open.

These pots are often used on the output shafts of gear-motors for position sensing, and a physical stop would break the pot if the motor ran outside of the 100 degree range.